# Small Basic Quiz, Going in reverse order

Tags: smallbasic

I am creating a Small Basic Quiz for school and i have used GraphicsWindow so i create buttons. My was working fine until i add other questions, because then it started to display them in reverse order.

Here's my Code:

```
GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor = "Black"
GraphicsWindow.CanResize = "True"
GraphicsWindow.Height = 650
GraphicsWindow.Width = 1200
GraphicsWindow.Top = 25
GraphicsWindow.Left = 50
GraphicsWindow.Title = "Advanced Computer Quiz
Goto Q1

'End Of GraphicWindow Settings'


'Start Of Game Varibles Settings'


'End Of Game Varibles Settings'


'Start Of Question One'

Q1:
GraphicsWindow.Clear()
GraphicsWindow.DrawText(1, 1, "Q.1")
GraphicsWindow.DrawText(1, 60, "What does CPU stand for?")
GraphicsWindow.drawtext(1, 120, "A. Computer Prossesing Unit   B. Central Prossesing Unit   C. Core Prossesing Unit")

Button_A = Controls.AddButton(" A ",7 ,160)
Button_B = Controls.AddButton(" B ",42 ,160)
Button_C = Controls.AddButton(" C ",77 ,160)

Controls.ButtonClicked = ButtonClicked_Input_Q1

Sub ButtonClicked_Input_Q1
  LastButtonClicked = Controls.LastClickedButton

  If LastButtonClicked = Button_A Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Incorrect ", " Answer ")
    Goto Q2

  ElseIf LastButtonClicked = Button_B Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Correct! ", " Answer ")
    Score = Score + 1 
    Goto Q2

  ElseIf LastButtonClicked = Button_C Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Incorrect ", " Answer ")
    Goto Q2

  EndIf
EndSub

' End Of Question One'


' Start Of Question Two'

Q2:
GraphicsWindow.Clear()
GraphicsWindow.DrawText(1, 1, "Q.2")
GraphicsWindow.DrawText(1, 60, "What does RAM stand for?")
GraphicsWindow.drawtext(1, 120, "A. Random Access Memory   B. Relative Atomic Mass   C. Random Active Movement")

Button_A = Controls.AddButton(" A ",7 ,160)
Button_B = Controls.AddButton(" B ",42 ,160)
Button_C = Controls.AddButton(" C ",77 ,160)

Controls.ButtonClicked = ButtonClicked_Input_Q2

Sub ButtonClicked_Input_Q2
  LastButtonClicked = Controls.LastClickedButton

  If LastButtonClicked = Button_A Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Correct! ", " Answer ")
    Score = Score + 1
    Goto Q3

  ElseIf LastButtonClicked = Button_B Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Incorrect ", " Answer ")
    Goto Q3

  ElseIf LastButtonClicked = Button_C Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Incorrect ", " Answer ")
    Goto Q3

  EndIf
EndSub

'End Of Question Two'


'Start Of Question Three'

Q3:
GraphicsWindow.Clear()
GraphicsWindow.DrawText(1, 1, "Q.3")
GraphicsWindow.DrawText(1, 60, "What are the Three types of Networks?")
GraphicsWindow.drawtext(1, 120, "A. Lan Dan Wan   B. Lan San Wan   C. Lan Gan Wan")

Button_A = Controls.AddButton(" A ",7 ,160)
Button_B = Controls.AddButton(" B ",42 ,160)
Button_C = Controls.AddButton(" C ",77 ,160)

Controls.ButtonClicked = ButtonClicked_Input_Q3

Sub ButtonClicked_Input_Q3
  LastButtonClicked = Controls.LastClickedButton

  If LastButtonClicked = Button_A Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Incorrect ", " Answer ")
    Goto Q4

  ElseIf LastButtonClicked = Button_B Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Correct! ", " Answer ")
    Score = Score + 1
    Goto Q4

  ElseIf LastButtonClicked = Button_C Then
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage(" Incorrect ", " Answer ")
    Goto Q4

  EndIf
EndSub

'End Of Question Three'
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems. The first is that you can't use a goto inside a Subroutine. This is making it so It can't continue to the next question. The second problem is that you don't have a pause after each question, so it won't stop after the first question. It will just blow through to the last. Here is the modified working code: **TDD527**

(Use the 'Import' button on the taskbar, and type in TDD527)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use flags to make sure that the graphics window doesn't change without you clicking something.